# Solving an Exact Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following d.e. that is exact.

$\cos \theta dr - (r\sin\theta - e^\theta)d\theta = 0$ which is the same as:

$\cos \theta dr + (-r\sin\theta + e^\theta)d\theta = 0$

I am trying to solve the equation. Here is what I have done so far:

$F(x,y) = \int cos\theta d\theta $

$F(x,y) = sin\theta + g(\theta)$

then:

$-rsin\theta + e^\theta = \frac{d}{d\theta}(sin\theta + g(\theta))$

$-rsin\theta + e^\theta = cos\theta + g'(\theta)$

This is where I'm stuck. Ideally things are supposed to cancel out here, but nothing does and I don't know how to proceed. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct form is $F(r,\theta) = \int cos\theta dr $ not $\color{red}{d\theta}$
$$F(r,\theta) = \int cos\theta dr=rcos\theta+ g(\theta)$$
hence $$-rsin\theta + e^\theta = \frac{d}{d\theta}(rcos\theta + g(\theta))=-rsin\theta+g'(\theta)\Rightarrow g'(\theta)= e^\theta\Rightarrow g(\theta)= \int e^\theta d\theta=e^\theta$$
$F(r,\theta)=r\cos\theta +e^\theta=c  $

Comment: Thank you. another question: is there a way to determine which variable is independent and which is dependant or not?

Comment: It is a two variable function, I do not understand your question.

Comment: disregard it, I understand the problem now